# Can't compile my program with two files in one program

Tags: java

Alright, I only know basic Java. I'm doing an assignment for my class on building a Sudoku checker board program consisting of two files. Typed in the first file, it compiled, typed in the second one and it comes back with an error saying:

> the second file is public, should be declared in a file named eholcomb_SudokuCheckerTest.java

Emphasis on the `.java`. But according to the instructions from the teacher and what he went over in class, I shouldn't have to do that since I already have one. Help!

Comment: Is the class name identical to the file name (not including the `.java` extension)?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?  Most IDEs should be able to sort this out for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Only one public class is allowed inside a .java file. You can have more than one non public classes. So make first level entry class as public and other one as non public.

Comment: That's a little erroneous, you can have "public" inner classes within the same file, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean ;)

Comment: This really isn't the normal way of doing this.  Presumably if Emily's been taught to make two different public classes, she's been told to put them in two separate files.